# Not acceptance of answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I see quite often that some answers which are clear and good referenced (containing verses etc) are not accepted. Not just mine, but others's as well. I am not talking about answers open to comments and personal opinions, but for example someone asks a question like "Is there any mention about something in Quran" and an answer comes with verses about that thing. This answer is definitely the proper answer and should be accepted.

Can site do something about it? Giving the owner of the question a warning maybe when the moderators saw such questions?

Comment: Now you see it's your choice to click the tick to Daniel's answer. If you don't click, then it will never be answered(Clicked).

Comment: @servantofWiser, I see what you did there :)

Answer (score 4):

It's up to the asker whether they want to accept an answer. Only he/she knows whether the answer was actually useful to him/her. The main point of acceptance is to bring a useful answer to the top of the answer list. If the asker neglects to accept an answer, upvotes from the community should accomplish the same purpose.

Comment: I know about how site works. But I am not talking about personal answers, of course in this case its depend on the owner of the question. I am talking about knowledge seeking questions and their undoubtable answers.

Comment: Again for that you should check out this haunting topic of this site... [Why Sectarianism is Ruining Your Site](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site) Disparities between your views and their views. A few also try to put in their version of Islam here, which is not allowed.